# Calculation of a curvilinear integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Please help to calculate the following integral.

> *Calculate $$\int_\gamma \frac{x\,dx + y\,dy+z\,dz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
>   where $\gamma$ is the way of class $\mathcal C^1$ which unites point on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ with a point on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=b^2$ with $a,b>0$.*

Comment: maybe introduce $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$

Comment: Take the partial derivatives of the denominator with regards to each variable, sum them, and notice that you get half of the numerator. So you're ultimately dealing with the integral of the derivative of the natural logarithm of the radius.

Comment: @datodatuashvili i've done that. Now i have r^2 in thw denominator. What is the next step

Comment: @Lucian could you please show how it would look, as I don't understand what partial derivative is.Thanks

Comment: See [nabla symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol) and [partial derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative). As for the LaTeX, just press the edit button on your own post, and/or browse through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Formatting_using_TeX) link.

Comment: "@Lucian: I've read about partial derivative , and there is an example" a
$$V=(r,h)={ {Pir^2h} \over 3} $$ 
The partial derivative of V with respect to r is $$ {dV\over dr} = {2pirh \over 3} $$ . The partial derivative with respect to h $$ {dV \over dh} = {pi r^2 \over 3} $$ 
Total derivative of V:
$$ {dV\over dr} = {{2pirh} \over 3} + {{pir^2}\over 3} {dh\over dr}$$
$${dV\over dh} = {{pir^2} \over 3} + {{2pirh} \over 3} {dr\over dh} $$

Comment: @Lucian And there says that the difference between the total and partial derivative is the elimination of indirect dependencies between variables in partial derivatives.

So if I get it right the partial derivative is made out of total derivative without its indirect dpendency between variables ( which in this case is 
$$ {pir^2 \over 3} {dh \over dr} and {{2Pi r h} \over 3} {dr \over dh} $$ respectively

Comment: @Lucian I also remember doing a kind of derivative at high school and using rules of derivation, i.e.  $$ f'=2x^3 +1=4x^2 $$ sth like that. Now how is that ordinary derivative is different from partial and total derivative? Which part of the current problem(solution) is partial derivative?

Comment: @Lucian Regarding the nabla. I've read a wiki article and from what I've understood that it is vector differential operator and it is defined by formula 
$$ \nabla = {\hat x {d \over dx}} + {\hat y {d \over dy}} + {\hat z {d \over dz}} $$ 
So if I got it right nabla is defined by the sum of three derivatives multiplied by unit vectors. Why is it being used in my problem, where is it applied exactly

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, then
$$
\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log(x^2+y^2+z^2)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(x,y,z)=\nabla \left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log(x^2+y^2+z^2)\right)=\nabla F,
$$
since 
$$
\nabla =\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\nabla F=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right).
$$
and hence if $\gamma(t)=\big(x(t),y(t),z(t)\big) : [0,T]\to \mathbb R^3$, is $C^1$, then
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz}{x^2+y^2+z^2} &=
\int_0^T \nabla F\big(\gamma(t)\big)\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt=F\big(\gamma(T)\big)-F\big(\gamma(0)\big) \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\|\gamma(T)\|^2}{\|\gamma(0)\|^2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{\|b\|}{\|a\|}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: could you please explain why F(x,y,z) = 1/2 delta log.... is that a formula?

Comment: @Zhivago: See updated version.

Comment: Dear Yiorgos, I can't figure out how did you come with the first line $$ F(x,y,z) ={1\over 2} {log(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$. Is that a rule of derivation (from the list of rules of derivation). Could you please explain?

Comment: $F=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is simply a function with the property that $(F_x,F_y,F_z)=\frac{(x,y,z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. I came up with it from experience. In this exercise, you NEED to find a function $F$, such that $$\nabla F\cdot (dx,dy,dy)=\frac{x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$, and $\log r$ does our job!

Comment: Be more specific on what exactly you do not understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12835/discussion-between-yiorgos-s-smyrlis-and-zhivago)